# Exclude Holidays Between two days

Tags: c#, list, datetime

Hi everybody i'm working a project about calculate specific working days.
My conditions are : Saturday is not holiday, it is working day.

I wrote this code everyting is okey skipped Sundays only , but i want to skip if contains a holiday date.

Problem : skipping Sunday but not skipping passing holiday list values.

Future Date Calculate function :

```
public DateTime CalculateFutureDate(DateTime fromDate, int numberofWorkDays,
                                     List<DateTime> holidays)
{
    var futureDate = fromDate;
    for (var i = 0; i < numberofWorkDays; i++)
    {
        if (
            futureDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday
           || (holidays != null && holidays.Contains(futureDate)))
        {
            futureDate = futureDate.AddDays(1);
            numberofWorkDays++;
        }
        else
        {
            futureDate = futureDate.AddDays(1);
        }
    }
    while (
           futureDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday
            || (holidays != null && holidays.Contains(futureDate)))
    {
        futureDate = futureDate.AddDays(1);
    }

    return futureDate;
}
```

Main function:

```
List<DateTime> holidayslist = new List<DateTime>();
holidayslist.Add(new DateTime(2016, 09, 7));
holidayslist.Add(new DateTime(2016, 09, 8));
holidayslist.Add(new DateTime(2016, 09, 9));
DateTime izinbaslangic = Convert.ToDateTime(dtpİzinBaslangicTarihi.Value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("tr-TR").DateTimeFormat);
dtpİzinBitisTarihi.Value = CalculateFutureDate(izinbaslangic, Int32.Parse(tbİzinGunu.Text), holidayslist);
```

Inputs :  izinbaslangic -> datetimepicker value  and  workingdays -> tbizingunu value

Expecting Outputs :  exclude holiday and weekends show in another datetimepicker new date.

Output :  Only skipping Weekends.Not skipping holidays.

Expecting Output Image :   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33yR1.jpg)

Comment: It would really help if you'd provide a [mcve] showing it not working... we don't know what your input, expected output and actual output are.

Comment: ok i will edit now

Comment: As a guess, does your datetimepicker return a date and a non-midnight time?

Comment: yes returning only date value inputs example i added the post

Comment: Can you add the outputs of `Console.WriteLine(izinbaslangic)` and `Console.WriteLine(holidayslist[0])`?

Comment: izinbaslangic - > 7.09.2016 11:48:01
holidayslist[0] ->  7.09.2016 00:00:00

Comment: You need to use `holidays.Contains(futureDate.Date)` then.

Comment: Oh yes thank  your very much , it will work ! i used to @Steve Codes and i changed to testDate.Date now working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would rewrite your code in the following way

```
public DateTime CalculateFutureDate(DateTime fromDate, int numberofWorkDays,
                                     List<DateTime> holidays)
{
    var futureDate = fromDate;
    while (numberofWorkDays != 0)
    {
        if (!isHoliday(futureDate, holidays))
            numberofWorkDays--;
        futureDate = futureDate.AddDays(1);
    }
    while (isHoliday(futureDate, holidays))
        futureDate = futureDate.AddDays(1);
    return futureDate;
}

bool isHoliday(DateTime testDate, List<DateTime>holidays)
{
    return (testDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday
           || (holidays != null && holidays.Contains(testDate.Date)));
}
```

The idea is simply to create a loop until the number of working days required is reduced to zero. Also isolating the logic to test for an holiday will help a lot in a better understanding of the code and avoid a dangerous duplication of the same logic

```
List<DateTime> holidayslist = new List<DateTime>();
holidayslist.Add(new DateTime(2016, 09, 7));
holidayslist.Add(new DateTime(2016, 09, 8));
holidayslist.Add(new DateTime(2016, 09, 9));

DateTime start = new DateTime(2016,9,7);
DateTime ending = CalculateFutureDate(start, 1, holidayslist);
Console.WriteLine(ending.ToString()); // 12/09/2016 00:00:00
```

Comment: Only working for first week in second week again skipping holiday days..

Comment: Can you provide the inputs used? Are the same of the question?

Comment: inputs 07.09.2016 and  1 day  output : 08.09.2016 now

Comment: I got 12.09.2016 (did you refresh the answer? I have changed a bit from the first revision)

Comment: I changed now and i added UI in first post , when i select 07.09.2016 and write 1 day showing 08.09.2016 interesting , your logic seems good

Comment: How did u get 12.09.2016 ?

Comment: Added the example used. Again, recheck the answer. In the first draft I had omitted the final part that loops until a working day is found if the first loop ends on an holiday date.

Comment: I found problem ; i changed testDate   to  testDate.Date  now working thank you !

Comment: All right then, really I don't know why you need this if all your dates don't contain any significant time part but I will update the answer accordingly